# How to prevent java.util.logging.Logger to display messages on standard output?

Tags: java, logging

I am using java.util.logging.Logger

But with storing messages in a log file, it also writes messages to the standard output (console).

How can I disable the logger to display messages on standard output?

Comment: which configuration file? I am new to logging. I have instantiated a Logger object and have started writing msgs to a log file using the Logger's methods. I haven't configured any config file.

Comment: http://www.hildeberto.com/2009/04/using-java-logging-configuration-file.html see here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to logging you should read [Java Logging Overview](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html).
You should also post your configuration

This snippet shows how to write log messages into a file:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Handler fh = new FileHandler("%t/wombat.log");
    Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);
    Logger.getLogger("com.wombat").setLevel("com.wombat",Level.FINEST);
    ...
}
```